# How to use tailwind with Vue using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use tailwindcss with my new project using VUE and typescript. 
I stored main.css inside `/src/assets/styles/main.css`
In my `main.ts` I've added `import './assets/styles/main.css'` at the very top.

But when I tried to running in the dev mode and added text-6xl in one of the text it seems tailwind is not taking effect.

Am I missing something? 
FYI: I've generated the vue code using `vue-cli` and also run `npx tailwind init` to create a tailwind config.

Thanks

Comment: What's in `main.css`? Have you [added Tailwind to your `postcss.config.js` file](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/#4-process-your-css-with-tailwind)?

Comment: main.css contains  `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; and @tailwind utilities;`

Comment: thanks, @Phil. I forgot to add that in my root directory. It works now :D